# Right approach for Nodejs API testing using supertest in multiple files?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I have written a couple of APIs' for which I would like to write test cases using supertest. I have two files, index.js and tester.js.

**index.js**

```
import tester from './tester';

const supertest = require('supertest');
const randomString = require('randomstring');
const app = require('../../dist/server');

const request = supertest(app);


describe('User signup and login', () => {

  tester(request);

  it('Signup -> New user signup test', (done) => {
    request.post('/users')
      .send(`userName=test${randomString.generate(7)}&password=12345678&firstName=name&lastName=name`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(201)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        return done();
      });
  });
});
```

**tester.js**

```
const randomString = require('randomstring');

export default function tester(request) {
  describe('testter ', () => {
    it('Signup -> New user signup test', (done) => {
      request.post('/users')
        .send(`userName=test${randomString.generate(7)}&password=12345678&firstName=nigilan&lastName=palladium`)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(201)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          return done();
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Now, when I run the index.js file, it runs both the test cases. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Embedding tests inside functions**

I don't understand the purpose of `tester.js`. It's a bit odd setup. But you did write the same test twice, and by calling the `tester` function inside the `describe` block, you are in effect placing the test inside that block. I would advise against wrapping test blocks inside such functions, unless you have a pressing reason to do so.

**Usage of supertest**

I think supertest is intended to be initialized in each test, i.e. so instead of writing

```
const request = supertest(app);

describe('User signup and login', () => {
  it('Signup -> New user signup test', (done) => {
    request.post('/users')
```

write this:

```
describe('User signup and login', () => {
  it('Signup -> New user signup test', (done) => {
    const request = supertest(app);
    request.post('/users')
```

This becomes critically important if you need to verify some cookie functionality using an actual agent. In that case, the agent carries the cookies in its internal state, and you most certainly don't want that state to shared between test.

**Marking the test as completed**

Mocha's done function can be passed directly to `expect`, so instead of writing:

```
.expect(201)
.end((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          return done();
        });
```

You can just write

```
.expect(201, done);
```

Alternatively, supertest can also be used as a promise, and mocha supports promises, so you can write

```
it("signup ...", () => {
    return request.post('/users') 
        ...
        .expect(201);
});
```

So this means that the return value of `expect` has a `then` function. Whether or not the function is actually called will determine if it behaves as a promise, or in "legacy" mode. If you return the promise in the mocha test, mocha will call `then`, and promise behavior is used.

Comment: Pete Thanks for your time. That is just an example and I don't intend to have same test in both the files. Second, I eventually end up in writing a function in another file after I was facing some error while initializing `app` in two files. So, I require app in each file and test some routes(with MongoDB connections), in second file, routes never succeeded. Third, I previously used .`end(done)` and had to change it, now I will switch back to that.

Comment: @Nigilan - I might have remembered incorrectly about passing `done` to `end` - I'm just fairly certain I've done it before (it's about a year ago I used supertest last). But according to the documentation, you can pass `done` to the `expect` function. I updated the answer accordingly.